# Changing clearcase_albd user password

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I found some information on IBM's website about changing the `clearcase_albd` user password.  (I need to change it for security reasons.)
Most of the information talks about having a release area, which was not set up at the beginning.

These are the sites that I found:

- "[Methods for changing the ALBD password for `albd_server.exe`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146207)"
- "[Creating a release area](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_ms_install_win.doc/creating_a_release_area.htm)"

From what I can tell, I may have to do everything manually.
I believe these are the steps I will have to take:

1. Change the `clearcase_albd` password
2. Change the logon information for the service on the server
3. Go to each client and change the logon information for the service (painfully.)

Is this what I will need to do?
Is there any shorter way to do this without revealing the password to users (or have it written in plain text anywhere?)
Are there any other pitfalls besides a user trying to log in and locking the `clearcase_albd` account?

If there are any other ways, I would love to know how to do this as painlessly as possible.
We are using ClearCase version 7.1.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I did those kind of operations, involving a sensitive change in the Clearcase settings impacting the users was...

Ask them to uninstall, and then re-install ClearCase, using a silent-install package that I have make (with, for instance here, the albd account new password).
See "[Installation scenario walkthrough: silent installation of ClearCase or ClearQuest with Installation Manager from a shared network drive](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_silent_inst_IM_netw_shareddrive.htm)".

It is still long and painful but:

- it is made at the user's initiative
- no confidential information is released

In your case, you need to make sure that the users trying to access ClearCase with their old ClearCase (using the old albd account password) won't block the albd account (because of too many tries with the wrong password).
If the account isn't blocked, then the users will simply see their ClearCase doesn't work, which will be a great incentive for them to un-install and then re-install, as you would have previously explained to them in an email.

Again, no sensitive information is communicated, and all their view, deliver/rebase in progress, checkout and so on will still work after the re-installation.

Comment: Would the steps that I said work?  There are only about 20 clients, so changing the service logon in their settings on that many computers wouldn't be TOO hard.  Unless there is something else that I am overlooking.

Comment: @Rubasu yes, that should work. I would still advise the users to close any ClearCase related windows before you change the log on password.